# How to use a server for redirecting clients to direct connecting to each other

Tags: java, sockets, server

I want to be able to connect (java)clients to each other without opening ports in their router or forwarding on their local network. I want to mimic the behavior of [webtrc](http://www.webrtc.org/) but in java, using a server for signaling. The server will have to receive session keys from both clients that wants to connect to each other, sending the first clients key to the second client and vice versa. After the signaling, the both clients can connect to each other using this key, and the packets will find their way through the router without opening ports and forwarding.

The goal is to make a framework out of this to be able to write applications that don't require a server with huge bandwidth that can read from one client and write to the other, for every pair of clients that wants to send data to each other. What I'm asking for is simply guidelines for this could be implemented.

TLDR: I want to be able to directly connect two clients, in two completely different networks, with the help of a public server and without any router configuration for the clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is called Hole punching

"Hole punching is a computer networking technique for establishing communications between two parties in separate organizations who are both behind restrictive firewalls. Used for applications such as online gaming, P2P and VoIP, both clients establish a connection with an unrestricted third-party server that uncovers external and internal address information for them. Since each client initiated the request to the server, the server knows their IP addresses and port numbers assigned for that session, which it shares one to the other." from wikipedia

also take a look on this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/743531)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read alot about hole punching since your comment and tried an implementation, but even though I'm using setReuseAddress(true) on both the socket to the server and the serversocket, I get "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" on the second bind. You answered my question, thanks. I will create another question for my implementation errors.